# Hoist slot content up one level

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I hope someone can help me out with this problem! I'm using a Table component from [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable), and I'm looking to create a wrapper component with a slot for content. The problem is, the component will only recognize content directly within its default slot. Nothing else is recognized.

Code:

```html
<template>
  <DataTable :value="data">
    <!-- These components are recognized -->
    <Column v-for="col in cols" :key="col.field" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" />
    <slot name="override" :cols="cols">
      <!-- These components are not -->
      <Column v-for="col in cols" :key="col.field" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" />
    </slot>
  </DataTable>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: // Array of data here,
      cols: // Array of cols here
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I checked their implementation, `DataTable` only looks in `$slots.default().children` for content. Since the content in `<slot name="override">` will show up as something along the lines of `$slots.default().children.children`, they are not recognized. Is there a way for me to hoist or inject any content (including the default content if possible) from the slot into its parent so the content appears in `$slots.default().children`?

Answer (score 0):

This template:

```html
<template>
  <slot name="heading">
    <h1>Default heading</h1>
    <h2>Default subheading</h2>
  </slot>
</template>
```

...is effectively the same as conditionally rendering the `<slot>` with `v-if="$slots.heading"` (which is only truthy when the `heading` slot is actually passed in) and moving its inner contents to a `v-else` block:

```html
<template>
  <slot v-if="$slots.heading" name="heading">
  </slot>
  <template v-else>
    <h1>Default Heading</h1>
    <h2>Default subheading</h2>
  </template>
</template>
```

So, you can use `v-if="$slots.override"` to conditionally render the `<slot>`, and move its contents (i.e., the `<Column>`s) into a `v-else` block:

```html
<DataTable :value="data">
  <slot v-if="$slots.override" name="override" :cols="cols" />
  <Column v-else v-for="col in cols" :key="col.field" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" />
</DataTable>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-conditional-slot?file=src/components/MyDataTable.vue)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately that doesn't really solve my problem, as any content inside of the slot will still be unrecognized by the component.

Comment: The content inside the `<slot>` is supposed to be used only when the slot is not provided. Moving that content into the `v-else` block has the same effect. Have you looked at the demo?

Comment: Yes I understand that the fallback content works in your demo. That's how I initially implemented it. However it doesn't work if you actually put custom content inside the slot. I've tried this solution to no avail.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I fully understand the problem. What is different about your code that makes the `v-else` solution not work for you?